# Oracle SQL: Error with CTE and row_number() syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, common-table-expression, row-number

#### Addressing @scaisEdge

I tried your query and get **error message**:

[image]

My original query gives **bad result**

[image]

But here is the result I need

[image]

---

**Summary:** CTE and row_number() gives error  `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

---

**Actual Question:**

I have a query that returns this

[image]

But I want it to return query that removes duplicates, i.e. `Date`, `Login ID` and `Subject` must be **Unique**.

However `ID number` should be **minimum**, and `Creation Date` should be **earliest hour of the day**

Here is desired output - notice the last entry had identical `Creation Date`, yet the output select entry with lowest `ID number`, i.e. `542`

[image]

Here is my current query

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
          TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS "Date",
          TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS "Login ID",  
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
   FROM  INCIDENT I 
   JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)
```

I was advised to use `CTE` and `row_number()` to eliminate duplicate dates, i.e. return long date with earliest time in day, but I get error with following query (`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`), hence please assist

```
with CTE as
(
SELECT t1.*,
       row_number() over (PARTITION BY I.CREATIONDATE ORDER BY I.CREATIONDATE) rn
FROM Mytable t1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn=1



SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
          TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS "Date",
          TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS "Login ID", 
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
FROM  INCIDENT I 
   JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)
```

Comment: Does there need to be a space between SELECT and *?

Comment: @BillHorvath made correction, error persists :-(

Comment: Have you tried to execute both queries separated?

Answer (score 1):

You should use group by TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),  TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT) only

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",

          TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME)                  AS Login_id,  
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
   FROM  INCIDENT I 
   JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY  TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)
```

Looking to your sample you could use a inner join  on min_date group by login_id for obatin olny the related rows

```
select t1.* from  (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(MIN(I.INCIDENTID))                  AS "Incident ID",
          MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)                      AS "Creation Date",
          TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')     AS login_id,  
          TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)                   AS "Email Subject"
   FROM  INCIDENT I 
   JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY'),
            TRIM(MO.DOMAINUSERNAME),
            TRIM(M.MESSAGESUBJECT)

) t1 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT  MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)  min_date, TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') login_id  
   FROM  INCIDENT I 
   JOIN  MESSAGE M
   ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
   JOIN   MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
   ON     M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID           
   GROUP BY  login_id 
) t2  on t1."Creation Date" = t2.min_date and t2.login_id  = t1.login_id
```

Comment: I don't think so, he uses this field twice, one with min and other one directly the attribute

Comment: @JaimeDrq   correct  the query should not use the  TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')   if the OP want the min  .. this column should be removed

Comment: I asked him about what he really wants, because of there are other parts in the query quite weird.

Comment: Hello @scaisedge. I updated my question. Hope it is more clear. Please assist if possible.

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge I shall try this and follow up ... thank you.

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge I'm struggling to get this to work --- will continue working on this

Comment: you have error?   show me the exact error message ..  wrong result?  show me a the actual result and your expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge I'll post screenshots in the next few days .... thank you for your guidance thus far

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge please see updated post `Addressing @scaisEdge`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to me understand this part:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       row_number() over (partition by MIN(I.CREATIONDATE) order by TO_CHAR(I.CREATIONDATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')) rn
FROM Mytable t1
```

`Partition by MIN(I.CREATIONDATE)` makes no sense to me. Can you please explain what do you really want with this query?

The partition by section is intended to provide a dimension/s for the rankings you are gonna create with the row_num. If it's allowed by the database (which I doubt), I cannot even imagine the output.

**EDITED**

Using row_num function, your query should look like this (change the `@fields` to your real name fields).
In there, you create "partition blocks" for each Login Id-Subject, and then order the rows using CREATIONDATE and ID fields, so for each group the record with the lesser combination of CREATIONDATE and less ID will receive a rank 1 in by the row_num

```
select
  q.@your_id_field, q.CREATIONDATE, q.@your_date_field, q.@your_login_id_field, q.@your_subject_field
from (
  select @your_id_field, CREATIONDATE, @your_date_field, @your_login_id_field, @your_subject_field,
    row_num() over (
      partition by @your_login_id_field, @your_subject_field
      order by I.CREATIONDATE asc, @your_id_field asc
    ) as rn
  -- I don't know your data, but your from maybe
  -- should look like this
  FROM INCIDENT I 
    JOIN MESSAGE M
      ON M.MESSAGEID = I.MESSAGEID
    JOIN MESSAGEORIGINATOR MO
      ON M.MESSAGEORIGINATORID = MO.MESSAGEORIGINATORID    
  ) q
where rn=1
```

Comment: Hello @jaime-drq I updated my question. Our system triggers multiple incidents for the same thing. Wish to keep `Date`, `Login ID` and `Subject` unique. However, `Date`, `Login ID` and `Subject` are duplicated with different `Incident ID` and long date-time, i.e. `Creation Date`. Hence I am trying to create query  that displays  `Date`, `Login ID` and `Subject`  only once, while keeping one `Incident ID` and one `Creation Date`.

Comment: Hi @Marium, I have updated the answer. Check it out and see if it works.

Comment: Hello @jaime-drq I shall try this soon ... thank you for your assistance

Comment: Why don’t you use in the sample data the real column names? That way would be easier to build the query...

Comment: Hello @jaime-drq I will work on this shortly. Thank you for your help thus far